# fixed text in text area using css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to fix a text in the beginning of text area, what I have right now is this :

```
  <div>
   <textarea class="title-text" placeholder="do something..." rows="2" maxlength="80"></textarea>
   <span class="before-title">I will,</span>
  </div>
```

the details in this link : http://jsbin.com/tolifa/1/watch?html,css,output

but the real issue is when the user types text bigger than the textarea size ( the size of textarea should be unchanged), the fixed text is not moved to top  and this issue appears : [image]

I need some JS to update to css `top` property of the class `before-title` when ever the textarea content is changed

Comment: must it be a textarea or can it be an editable element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**html**

```
<div id="holder"><textarea class="title-text" placeholder="do something I'm really good at" rows="3" maxlength="80"></textarea>
<span class="before-title">Pour Combien,</span>

    <span id="testscrol"></span></div>
```

**css**

```
.before-title, .title-text {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.before-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-size: 45px;
    z-index: 1 ; 
}
#holder {
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.title-text {
  text-indent: 340px; /* change this value */
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index : 99999 ;   
}
```

**JavaScript(jquery)**

```
  function h(e) {
    var height =  e.scrollTop; 
    $("#testscrol").html(e.scrollTop) ; 
    $(".before-title").css({'top' : 9 - height });
    
}
$('textarea').each(function () {
  h(this);
}).on('scroll' , function(){
    h(this) ; 
});
```

## #Live Demo#

**~error fixed by zerzer~**

Comment: actually this is great but not quite the trick that i need, the text area height should stay unchanged and the fixed text need to move up, just like if it was part of the user written text

Comment: Thanks for the guide, i've added what i need based on your fiddle here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/ttwbxwon/66/ i'll marque this solved , thanks

Comment: "should be unchanged" I didn't  touch this part sorry for that and thankz I'll update the answer

Answer (score 3):

a solution without javascript would be:

http://jsfiddle.net/vsync/qu0q8qgc/

```
<div class='tArea' contenteditable data-fixedtitle='fixed title: '>This is the default text</div>
```

### CSS

```
.tArea{ font:20px/1.2 arial; border:1px solid #CCC; padding:1em; margin:1em; height:5em; overflow:auto;
    &::before{ content:attr(data-fixedtitle); color:red; }
    > span{ float:left; color:red; }
    > p{ margin:0; padding:0; }
}
```

Comment: a little js i needed if you want to simulate a full placeholder functionality